# Manual testing for GPS on ios

Tags: testing, manual-testing

I'm a newbie in testing area. I have an application which has the facility to use gps and I don't have garmin tracker. I have done few tests on gps but i don't feel it's sufficient.

How to test gps manually?
What are the ways and methods to test it? please, suggest some testcases for it.

Comment: please explain your question. what's use of gps in your ios app?

Comment: Gps is used to know the location and it will continuously update me in regular intervals of time.For this i want to test the accuracy and efficiency of it.

Comment: then install your application on your mobile device and check it on different physical location.

Comment: Thank you!!i did few tests on it but i didn't feel it sufficient. So i asked question here.

Answer (score 0):

1.Need to test while traveling how the application is working with Gps connection.

2.How the Application is behaving while we got a **call/Message**.

3.How the Application is behaving while battery low /Automatic turn off u r phone,the current data is saved in data base properly or not

4.Need to check **Battery life** while using GPS

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your done with smoke testing!, In that case start with Interruption testing.

1. Keep moving in a place, check the your GPS connectivity.
2. Travel to remote places where you feel the GPS can't be tracked. Check how your application responds.
3. Try receiving call while using the Application.
4. Place an alarm, check how your application responds during alarm work.
5. Check when your device is about to die, how the application responds. Since you'l be using GPS, chances of u'r battery drain is too high.
6. Check with Notification. how your application behaves.
7. Switch off your GPS, see if an appropriate alert is provided.